# Click an input to trigger focus event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have an input with `ng-focus="..."` directive.
I'm trying to get this input be focused by clicking on it but it seems does not work that way.

I've tried to type something in it by `sendKeys` and then to click on it but I still see characters appear in the input but further clicking does not trigger a focus event.

```
input.sendKeys('0').then(function() {
    input.click().then(refreshModel).then(function (model) { // here I can see 0 in my input
        expect(...).toBe(...); // input does not get focused here
    });
});
```

Comment: Check the compatibility of ng-click against the version of angular that you're using

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. Maybe use this plunker to refine your question: http://plnkr.co/edit/2Yj4Srhey6ODCtlNy1AZ?p=preview

Comment: @mainguy my problem is to focus an input in a protractor test.

Comment: Uh, sorry. I haven't seen that. Ignore my silly comment, please:-)

Comment: Could you try to isolate the `click()` without any other action to identify where does your problem come from?

Answer (score 0):

If I click the input field my ng-focus is triggered, maybe some bug got fixed?

```
this.testField = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.model('testModel'));
this.testField.click();
```